# phpcs Is there a rule to disallow empty lines?

Tags: php, phpcs, psr-2

Is there a rule that I can use with phpcs that limits the number of consecutive empty lines to e.g. 3? I currently use PSR2, which does not take this into consideration at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is one called `no_extra_consecutive_blank_lines`, you can find more on available rules [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer). I do not however know how you would be able to specify the number of lines to allow.

Seeing as we are busy with TypeScript at the moment we are also looking at TSLint, which does seem to allow specifying number of lines; [Example-TSLINT](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-consecutive-blank-lines/) (just FYI).